# pass radio button value

Tags: javascript, php

I am using this javascript code for passing radio button value from one page to another.
This javascript code is using `for`-loop and I  want to use infinite loop in my programming.

```
 <script langauge="javascript">
   function getresult(){
 for(i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    if(document.forms[0].elements[i].checked)
    {
       var the_value = document.forms[0].elements[i].value;
    }
 }
 self.opener.Add_Define.OPRID.value=the_value;
 window.close();
}
</script>
```

How can I do this without a loop?

Comment: You mean you want to do it without using `for` loop?

Comment: Whats wrong with using a loop?

Comment: `i am not use loop in my programming`, then what you prefer for looping items?

Comment: yes,without using for loop?

Comment: @user2872614 can you use jquery?

Comment: A for loop is the appropriate and idiomatic tool to use here. There is no reason not to use one.

Comment: tell me how can use jquery?

Comment: @user2872614 you have to include jquery library in your file and then using jquery script you will be able to get selected radio button value without using loop in your script.

Comment: how can i use this code with infinite loop.....???

Answer (score 0):

Add this path in header like how do we include js file (you can also put this file locally)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
```

And then use following code in your script. where "myradiobutton" is the name of your radio button.

```
var the_value=$('input[name="myradiobutton"]:radio:checked').val();
```

Comment: <script langauge="javascript">
   function getresult(){
 for(i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    if(document.forms[0].elements[i].checked)
    {
       var the_value = document.forms[0].elements[i].value;
    }
 }
 self.opener.Add_Define.OPRID.value=the_value;
 window.close();
}
</script>

Comment: @user2872614, you don't need to write any loop( say for loop)...only you need to put the name of the radio button. please check with --- var the_value=$('input[name="myradiobutton"]:radio:checked').val();---also in which myradiobutton is under double quote ("").

Comment: don't forget to include jquery library. To access  the path what I have mentioned ,you need to have Internet connectivity otherwise you can download the library and put it locally and change the path in header.